# HttpResult or HttpError with response dto does not get serialized into body

Tags: servicestack

i am trying to return a BadArguments Error along with a custom DTO in the body:

```
var result = new HttpResult(response, "application/json", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

I have tried to use HttpError, HttpResult, setting the response by hand etc etc but i get only

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BadRequest
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,22 Win32NT/.NET
X-Powered-On: ITDEVELOP36-PC
Test-Header-ValidationError: TestValidationError
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 26 Feb 2015 10:36:12 GMT

b
Bad Request
0
```

No body, no content type is set. What am i missing?
ServiceStack version is 3.3.6.29935.

Comment: there is a overload to the HttpResult that gets the responsetext and the content type as arguments.

Comment: Can you show the code that you've already tried?

Comment: var result = new HttpResult(response, "application/json", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
when i use this status code the result returned to the client is stripped from the content type and response dto. see initial entry.

Comment: Are you creating this directly from the service?  Or some response filter?

Comment: i have tried both with no luck. The funny thing was that in the response filter i get to override anything i want but!!! if i set the StatusCode to 400 then the framework overrides everything giving the initialy mentioned result. funny thing!!!

Comment: There must be something else going on in your application (filters, global filter, etc...).  And I don't know what "response" is in your sample.  I just did a quick test on 3.9.71 and when my service does: "return new HttpResult(new { error = "oops"}, "application/json" ,HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);" I get a proper HTTP 400 with my error object in the body.  Works fine.  Can you show more of your code?

Comment: i can just confirm that it is version specific. i used the latest free version 3.9.71 and it works. so we have two options. go to 3.9.71 or, and this would be my first and only choice, use web api. thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After poking a while i have found that the ServiceStack framework works just fine. Even in the older version we are using.
The issue exist only when the web.config enables the  section.
After removing this section all worked well.

Comment: Can you please specify which section it was? I am running into same issue.

Comment: @BrikeshKumar I am sorry but I don&#39;t have the code anymore. maybe do a new project and see if it works and the compare the configs, or remove config settings until it works.

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate it!! Since your response was very old, so I was not sure If you still remember the context